# Limit in the sense of distributions of $n^2\chi_{[-1/n,0[}$ - $n^2\chi_{]0,1/n]}$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, distribution-theory

Limit in the sense of distributions of $n^2\chi_{[-1/n,0[} - n^2\chi_{]0,1/n]}$
Here's what I tried:

Let's set $T=n^2 \chi_{[-1/n,0[}$

We have for $ \phi \in \mathcal{D} $

\begin{align}
<T,\phi>&=\int_{-1/n}^{0}n^2\phi(x)dx\\
&=\int_{-n}^{0}\phi(\dfrac{y}{n^2})dy\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\chi_{[-n,0[}(y)\phi(\dfrac{y}{n^2})dy
\end{align}

I used the substitution $ y=n^2x $ above.

Since $ \phi \in \mathcal{D} $, we can use the dominated convergence theorem, which yields:

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}<T,\phi>&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\chi_{[-\infty,0[}(y)\phi(0)dy\\
&=\phi(0)\int_{-\infty}^{0}dy
\end{align}

Which is where I stopped. I have a particular reservation with the closed bracket on $-\infty$, is that allowed ?

Any further indications ? Thanks.

Comment: @geetha290krm hello, I had made a mistake in the question form the brackets of the second term so I edited it. Does the limit in the question still not exist ? Can you please elaborate why ?

Comment: I don't mean to be contrarian but this was a question in an entrance exam, I doubt the limit would not exist ? I'm sorry, can you elaborate why it doesn't exist ? And why I can't separate the two terms ?

Comment: $\int [n^2\chi_{[-1/n,0[}$ - $n^2\chi_{]0,1/n]}] \phi \to \infty$ whenever $\phi (0) >0 $.

Comment: My educated guess would be something like $\delta'$.  The reason being that if you integrate that function times $f$, you get $n^2 [-F(-1/n) + 2F(0)  - F(1/n)]$, which by a generalization of the $1/n$ argument to $h$ and l'Hopital's rule would approach a limit of $-F''(0) = -f'(0)$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I'm sorry I still don't understand your argument. What if $\phi(0)<0$ ?

Comment: @DanielSchepler hello, I assume $F$ is the antiderivative of the test function $f$. I didn't know we could simply use that technique. The brackets being open/closed doesn't any effect ?

Comment: Yes, $F$ is the antiderivative of $f$; and yes, the brackets being open/closed makes no difference since a single point has measure zero.

Comment: @DanielSchepler thank you for your help !

Comment: @geetha290krm What are you talkinig about?  The distributional limit is the distributional limit of the Dirac Delta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi \in C_C^\infty$ and $\delta'_n(x)=-n^2\text{sgn}(x)\xi_{[-1/n,1/n]}$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
\langle \delta'_n,\phi\rangle&=n^2 \int_{-1/n}^{0}\phi(x)\,dx-n^2\int_0^{1/n}\phi(x)\,dx\\\\
&=n^2 \int_{-1/n}^0 (\phi(0)+\phi'(0)x+O(x^2))\,dx-n^2 \int_0^{1/n} (\phi(0)+\phi'(0)x+O(x^2))\,dx\\\\
&=-\phi'(0)+O(1/n)
\end{align}$$

Letting $n\to\infty$, we find that in distribution $\delta'_n\to \delta'$.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply ! Is the answer I provided below not valid ?

Comment: @tareqath You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: i'm fully convinced with your answer, I'm just wondering if the answer I wrote below (using the antiderivative) is not valid ?

Comment: @tareqath I think that it is correct.  But you're missing a factor of $2$ of $F(0)$.

Comment: you're right, thank you.

Comment: @tareqath You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to first take the derivative:
$$\delta_n' = n^2 \left( \delta_{-1/n} - 2\delta_0 + \delta_{1/n} \right).$$
Thus,
$$
\langle \delta_n', \varphi \rangle
= n^2 \left( \varphi(-1/n) - 2\varphi(0) + \varphi(1/n) \right).
$$
When $n\to\infty$ this converges to $\varphi''(0) = \langle \delta'',\varphi\rangle.$ (If you don't see this directly you can replace $n$ with $1/h$ and take the limit as $h\to 0.$)

So, $\delta_n' \to \delta'',$ i.e. $\delta_n \to \delta' + C$ for some constant $C.$ Studying the original limit with $\varphi \equiv 1$ on for example $[-1, 1]$ then shows that $C=0.$

Comment: thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Using the tip from @DanielSchepler I did the following:

$T=n^2\chi_{[-1/n,0[} - n^2\chi_{]0,1/n]}$

We have for $ \phi \in \mathcal{D} $ and $F$ its antiderivative:

\begin{align}
<T,\phi>&=n^2(F(0)-F(-\dfrac{1}{n})-F(\dfrac{1}{n})+F(0)\\
&=n^2(-F(\dfrac{1}{n})-F(-\dfrac{1}{n})+2F(0))
\end{align}
using Taylor's expansion I get:

$ F(\dfrac{1}{n})=F(0)+\dfrac{1}{n}F'(0)+\dfrac{1}{2n^2}F''(0)+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\theta(1/n^2) $

and

$F(\dfrac{-1}{n})=F(0)-\dfrac{1}{n}F'(0)+\dfrac{1}{2n^2}F''(0)+\dfrac{1}{n^2}\theta(1/n^2) $

We finally get
$ 
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}<T,\phi>=-F''(0)=-\phi'(0)=<\delta',\phi> $

Comment: Shouldn't that be $\frac{1}{2n^2} F''(0)$ in both?  (Also, incidentally, `\langle T, \phi \rangle` will give $\langle T, \phi \rangle$ which is a bit prettier.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler you're right, thanks for pointing it out.